# setting the Vary head from firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm unable to successfully set the Vary header in a firebase function.

My code:

```
res.set('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding');
```

Server response:

```
vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding, cookie, authorization
```

I have several functions that return data that I want cached based purely on the 'Accept-Encoding' header.  But no matter what I do, firebase appears to overwrite my header with its own.  Crucially, it's adding cookie, authorization which break my cache.

My functions are accessed by a url that is rewritten using firebase hosting.  According to these [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache) it should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting automatically adds these headers to `Vary` to prevent accidental cross-user cache leaks. This can still work perfectly well with caching, as Firebase Hosting also strips all cookies from the `Cookie` header except one named `__session`.

If you have content that does not vary based on the `Authorization` header, I'd recommend not including that header in your request to the function (since your function should not be using it anyway unless it's part of the `Vary`).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response.  Maybe I was asking the wrong question.  I get a lower cache hit rate than expected.  I made the (possibly false) assumption that it was because of the vary header.  But as you say, I am not passing it in the request, so it may not be that.

Comment: How are you evaluating cache hit rate? Of note is that content is cached on each individual edge node, so a hit will only occur if a request for the same content reaches the same edge node.

Comment: I've not measured it accurately.  But I've noticed just from running on my machine at home that my queries reach my server quite regularly when I believe they should be served from the CDN.  I cache things for several hours, but often just a few minutes (or seconds) passes sometimes and my query reaches my server.  I've not noticed a pattern